# Problems importing audiolazy in Python's IDLE

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to open 4 packages to run in Python 3.12: pandas, matplotlib, audiolazy, and midiutil.

I am running the following script in IDLE:

```
import sys
import subprocess
for package in ['pandas','matplotlib', 'audiolazy', 'midiutil']:
     subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', package])
```

I have no problems importing pandas, matplotlib and midiutil with the following script:

```
import pandas as pd  
import matplotlib.pylab as plt  
from midiutil import MIDIFile
```

But when I run: `from audiolazy import str2midi` or `import audiolazy` to try to verify if it had installed correctly, I have the following errors:

from audiolazy import str2midi
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in 
from audiolazy import str2midi
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/audiolazy/**init**.py", line 67, in 
).init_package(**path**, **name**, **doc**)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/audiolazy/_internals.py", line 117, in init_package
modules = get_modules(package_name, module_names)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/audiolazy/_internals.py", line 59, in get_modules
return [get_module(name) for name in module_names]
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/audiolazy/_internals.py", line 58, in get_module
return **import**(".".join([package_name, name]), fromlist=[package_name])
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/audiolazy/lazy_analysis.py", line 23, in 
from collections import deque, Sequence, Iterable
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/collections/**init**.py)

import audiolazy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in 
import audiolazy
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/audiolazy/**init**.py", line 67, in 
).init_package(**path**, **name**, **doc**)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/audiolazy/_internals.py", line 117, in init_package
modules = get_modules(package_name, module_names)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/audiolazy/_internals.py", line 59, in get_modules
return [get_module(name) for name in module_names]
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/audiolazy/_internals.py", line 58, in get_module
return **import**(".".join([package_name, name]), fromlist=[package_name])
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/audiolazy/lazy_analysis.py", line 23, in 
from collections import deque, Sequence, Iterable
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/collections/**init**.py)

I have tried to import Sequence from collections (having previously imported collections) with this script `from collections import Sequence` but I continue having a similar problem:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in 
from collections import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/collections/**init**.py)

I would really appreciate any help you may provide to be able to import audiolazy successfully in Python's IDLE.

Comment: Are you certain the package is compatible with python 3.12?

Comment: Audiolazy package and the ImportError related to 'Sequence' indicates that the Sequence class is not available in the collections module in `Python 3.12`. This is because, in Python 3.3 and later, collections. Sequence was moved to the `collections.abc` module as `collections.abc.Sequence`.

Comment: Also check this [issue](https://github.com/danilobellini/audiolazy/issues/15). It talks about this exact problem.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your comments! @PaulH: According to its website (https://pypi.org/project/audiolazy/), the latest version of audiolazy is for Python 3.6.

Comment: @sneha and Fanchen Bao: Thank you very much for this tip and the example provided! I'm quite new using Python, so I am not sure how can I import Sequence correctly from collections.abc within IDLE every time I try to import audiolazy. I attempted the following script: >> import collections.abc
>> from collections.abc import Sequence
>> import audiolazy , but I am still having the same error regarding collections and Sequence after attempting it for audiolazy. How could I change the instruction for collections.abc?

Answer (score 0):

This import error has nothing to do with IDLE.  You would get the same error running your code directly with Python.  The following is the IDLE shell with 3.13.0a2:

```
>>> from collections.abc import Sequence
>>> Sequence
<class 'collections.abc.Sequence'>
```

You likely have to upgrade (edit) the audiolazy code to do the same.